# FirstOrDefualtAsync C# no hace match con strings

Tags: c#

Recibo un string Name por request, y en seguida paso a buscarlo a la base de datos, el string que envio como request se que existe en la base de datos, pero al hacer el firstOrDefaultAsync me retorna null, porque? pd: c# v6

Ejemplo:

```
request.Name = " CORPORACION UMBRELLA TEST"
```

Y en mi busqueda a la base de datos es lo siguiente:

```
string companyName = await _context.Empresas.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name.Trim() == request.Name.Trim());
//companyName = null en este punto me retorna null 
if(companyName != null)
{
   //DO Actions
}
```

***Actualización:***
El problema es que me retorna null, aún si los datos son iguales porque me retorna null?

Copie el registro tal cual de la DB y lo pegue en mi body en TS, y el linter detecta unos espacios que a la vista no se ven pero con el linter los pinta amarillos, en resumen no son simples espacios en blanco sino caracteres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca una foto de la BD demostrando que existe

Comment: Es una base de prueba y practicamente solo existen 5 registros donde trato de hacer match, cuando envio el dato por post, pero ya encontre el inconveniente al parecer algunos espacios los esta tomando como un caracter  u00A0 y otros como espacios en blanco ' ' tendre que normalizar los espacios

Comment: https://programmerclick.com/article/66841657796/

Comment: El carácter u00A0 se conoce como Non-Braking Space. Sirve para que a pesar de haber un espacio en blanco ese no se use como corte al momento de dividir el texto en varias líneas sino que todo aparezca junto. Es diferente al u0020 que es el espacio normal. Simplemente las cadenas no son iguales.